# how to use count on a groupby using extension methods?

Tags: .net, linq, count, group-by, extension-methods

I need to use get count(*) like sql server on linq, how can I use extenstion methods to do that ?
here is what I am trying to do

```
var test = empire.Case_Offence.Join( empire.Offences , w => w.OffenceId , 
                       x => x.Id ,
                      ( w , x ) => new { w.Id , w.OffenceId , x.Name  } )
                       .GroupBy( ww => new {ww.Name, ww.Id,ww.OffenceId } ) ;
```

tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var test = empire.Case_Offence.Join( empire.Offences , w => w.OffenceId , 
                       x => x.Id ,
                       ( w , x ) => new { w.Id , w.OffenceId , x.Name  } )
                       .GroupBy( ww => new {ww.Name, ww.Id,ww.OffenceId } )
                       .Select ( g => new { Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count() } );
```

`test` will then be a set of anonymous types with two parameters - `Key` - the group-by key, and `Count` - the number of items with that key.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if I can use GroupJoin for this case ?

Comment: Not in this case I don't think (at least, you wouldn't be able to get exactly the same results using GroupJoin alone), although it does depend somewhat on your input data, and your requirements in terms of the output.